# Вложенный роутинг vue, жизненый цикл и загрука данных

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

У меня такой вопрос к экспертам:
Используется вложенный роутинг - например:

```
{
      path: 'root',
      component: Root,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'child',
          component: Child,
          children: [
            {
              path: 'child-child',
              component: ChildChild
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

на каждом уровне в mounted происходит обращение к апи за данными, причем каждый компонент нижнего уровня зависит от данных своего родителя.
Казалось бы все гуд, но вот незадача - mounted происходит снизу в верх. Т.е на момент mounted самого нижнего по вложенности компонента, данных которые должны были ему придти от его родителя еще нет.... Как с этим можно справиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В независимости от того, как монтируются вложенные маршруты, данные с API не приходят синхронно, либо не рендерите потомков пока нет данных, либо складывайте данные в Vuex, в дочерних компонентах делайте watch на эти переменные и как они поменяются рендерите в потомках результаты.

Второй вариант мне кажется более правильным. Я бы сделал именно так.

Comment: Да, именно так и сделал.